Swift MacOS http POST JSON Return value
I want to return the value of 'entry' in a func. Here is what I have so far. Please offer a good way to use a func, to return the value.
I'm working off the instructions found here: Connecting IOS Apps to SQL
It's pretty difficult to understand. I'm new to this. This is a MacOS app, not IOS.
And I only want the value of 'entry' for a return value.
import Foundation
import Combine

@MainActor
final class DailyOutLookModel: ObservableObject {


struct dailyOutlook: Decodable {

let DOY: String
let error: Bool
let datex: String
let entry: String       // The value of this is what I want to display
}



weak var delegate: Downloadable?


let networkModel = Network()

func downloaddailyoutlook(parameters: [String : Any], url: String) {
    
    let request = networkModel.request(parameters: parameters, url: url)
    
    networkModel.response(request: request) { (data) in
        let model = try! JSONDecoder().decode([dailyOutlook]?.self, from:data) as [dailyOutlook]?
        self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model! as [dailyOutlook])
        
    }
}





func buildIt() -> String {

var paramX = ["doy": getDayOfYear()]

downloaddailyoutlook(parameters: paramX, url: URLServices.dailyoutlook)

func didReceiveData(data: Any) {
    
    var dataX = (data as! dailyOutlook)
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
    }
}
return dataX.entry    // return value of entry here!


}




}



show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code. Enough code and data to compile and run a simple example of your problem. Search SO, there are plenty of posts that uses https POST requests and decode the resulting JSON data.

You are decoding an array of Optional which is what [DailyOutlook]?.self translates to in swift. Then you are force unwrapping it with try!(forcing a crash if nil is decoded) then casting it back to an optional. Additionally you are then casting it in your function as! DailyOutlook this will always crash, because array can never be cast as a single value of type DailyOutlook. Try the following approach and look at the difference and try to understand what is happening here.
          //try? will not crash but instead return optional nil if an error is thrown
 let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode([dailyOutlook]?.self, from:data) ?? [] //the ?? [] provides an empty array without crashing if the json decode fails
 
 print(model.count) //prints to the console the number of elements. This should be done with error handling such as a do try catch statement, but is beyond the scope of this question.
 for outlook in model {
      //here outlook is one element of the array stored in model
      self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: outlook)//note there is no reason to cast here because your function has an argument of type Any
 }

example:
@MainActor
final class DailyOutLookModel: ObservableObject {


    struct dailyOutlook: Decodable {

        let DOY: String
        let error: Bool
        let datex: String
        let entry: String       // The value of this is what I want to display
    }

    weak var delegate: Downloadable?


    let networkModel = Network()

    func downloaddailyoutlook(parameters: [String : Any], url: String) {

        let request = networkModel.request(parameters: parameters, url: url)

        networkModel.response(request: request) { (data) in
    
        let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode([dailyOutlook]?.self, from:data) ?? []
        self.delegate?.didReceiveData(data: model)

        }
    }

    func buildIt() -> String {
        //code for this function
    }

    func didReceiveData(data: Any?) -> String { //add return statement here

        if var dataX = (data as? dailyOutlook) {
            return dataX.entry    // return value of entry here!
        }
        //handle error safely
    }
}


Also your return statement is outside of your function try reformatting your code and keeping everything neatly in the braces.

Don't use try? when decoding, use try with a do/catch
